# How to get device user agent information in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm building a flutter app which needs to send user agent information along with the http request. I'm using [http dart package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) to send requests. How to get user agent string in flutter and use it with http package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I done it by calling native methods in flutter. First you have to add method channel in android Main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                    if (call.method.equals("getUserAgent")) {
                        result.success(System.getProperty("http.agent"));
                    } else {
                        result.notImplemented();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Then `getUserAgent()` method can be called in flutter like below

```
Future<String> _getUserAgent() async {
  try {
    return await platform.invokeMethod('getUserAgent');
  } catch (e) {
    return 'Unknown';
  }
}
```

Comment: When I add the above code in my mainActivity.kt file it gives several error:

`(20, 15): Expecting member declaration`

Answer (score 2):

You can get it in a cross-platform way by using the `flutter_user_agent` library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_user_agent.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_user_agent/flutter_user_agent.dart';

...

    String ua = await FlutterUserAgent.getPropertyAsync('userAgent');
```

Comment: This doesn't work any more:
The plugin `flutter_user_agent` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me by using `flutter_user_agent` library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_user_agent
as mentioned above

```
String _userAgent = await FlutterUserAgent.getPropertyAsync('userAgent');

    final _response = await http.get(_url, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
      'User-Agent': '${_userAgent.toLowerCase()}',
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Found a library that does it. It would be interesting to look at what the library does, i don't think it's needed to implement a library for that.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/user_agent

An example on how you would use it:

```
main() async {
    app.get('/', (req, res) async {
        var ua = new UserAgent(req.headers.value('user-agent'));

        if (ua.isChrome) {
            res.redirect('/upgrade-your-browser');
            return;
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to add a user-agent to the http client, you can do it this way:

```
Future<http.Response> fetchPost() {
  return http.get(your_url,
    // Send user-agent header to your backend
    headers: {HttpHeaders.userAgentHeader: "your_user_agent"},
  );
}
```

You can look at `HttpHeaders`to see the full list of predefined headers, although `headers` take a map, you could create your own header if you want.

Comment: I asked how user agent string is created in flutter. I want to send it to the server. like,
`String userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent");` can be used to get user agent in android.

Comment: @JavierMendonca I believe you misunderstood udara's question. I am also looking for a solution to get the device's user agent using Flutter.

Comment: @nemoryoliver I think my answer will help you :)

Comment: Did you use the http package in the first code example? The app variable, does it stand for the http library?

Comment: Your answer is in totally different direction. He is asking to get user agent of android device so http request have correct user agent as per user device instead of same for all devices.

Comment: @NatwarSingh the user doesn't even mention android in his question, I tried to give a generic question considering it could be a cross platform app.. I would like to know a better solution then, what do you think is the best way to solve this?