# How to check if Flutter app in running in webview

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have built a web app in Flutter and I want to check where the app is running.
My app runs in the normal browser, in Microsoft Teams and in a WebView within another Flutter app.

In all cases the kIsWeb bool is true.

With the device_info_plus package I only get errors...

And with the web_browser_detect (on iOS) only safari back as the browser (even if it is in the webview)

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: The error I get with device_info_plus is:

Error: UnimplementedError: webBrowserInfo() has not been implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are needing to look at `userAgent`. See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67644049/233382
or this answer
[How to get device user agent information in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039049/how-to-get-device-user-agent-information-in-flutter)